# Validating user input before inserting in a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, control-flow

I am writing a simple program as an exercise where the user enters the grades(char type) and the system validates the input, comparing the user input against a vector containing the grades.

I am having issues writing logic that checks if the input is valid or not, converts the input to uppercase, and then inserts the input into the vector. I want the program to go back to the beginning of the loop if the user don't enter a valid character and ask again for valid input. Right now the program validates the input and send the message out "Please enter a valid grade", but insert the input into the vector regardless if it is right or wrong. That's not the desired result.

I just started learning c++ so sorry for the messy code.

This is the function that get the user input, convert to uppercase and validates against the vector.

```
void gradesInput() {
    char upperGrade;
    bool result = true;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dGrades.size() && result == true; i++)
    {

            cout << "Please enter your student grades...\n";
            cin >> dGrades[i];
            upperGrade = toupper(dGrades[i]);
            result = validateInput(upperGrade);
            if (result == true){
                cout << "That's a valid grade.";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Please enter a valid grade.";
            }
    }
}
```

This is the function that runs the validation:

```
bool validateInput(char uInput) {
    vector <char> grades(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    bool result = binary_search(grades.begin(), grades.end(), uInput);

    return result;
}
```

And this are the vector and array declaration that I am using:

```
std::vector <char> dGrades(10);
static const char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F' };
```

I am inserting the user input to the dGrades vector after comparing the input against the array and converting to upper case.

I will appreciate the help or any guidance.

Comment: Use other looping constructs such as `while` or `do-while`, where you increment the index instead of the index being automatically incremented.

Comment: ...and use a `temp` to read user input, only insert it when it is valid. Other than that you seem to have all the parts, just in the wrong order

Comment: You can get rid of the creation of the `vector<char>` in `validateInput()` if you declare `arr` to be a `const array<char, 5>` instead. The `std::array` class has `begin()` and `end()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop until the user entered a valid value each of the 10 times you ask for input at a high level. So in each of the iterations of your for loop, you want to loop until the user gives valid input. Only then do you push into the vector. I'd suggest you add it as a function returning a char once valid input is found:

```cpp
char getValidGrade() {
    char result;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter your student grades...\n";
        cin >> result;
        result = toupper(result);
        if (validateInput(result)) {
            cout << "That's a valid grade.";
            return result;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please enter a valid grade.";
        }
    }
}
```

Call it in `gradesInput()` like this:

```cpp
void gradesInput() {
    for (auto &grade : dGrades) {
        grade = getValidGrade();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked like a charm. I have been two days trying to solve this simple problem.